# Unable to redirect app back to its facebook page tab

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I’ve just created a Facebook app, this is my first attempt, while completing everything as stated I am stucked at this strange situation:

After authentication when user allows the app, the app get redirects my browser outside the Facebook to the website page where my website is hosted, instead of redirecting just the iframe remaining inside page tab.

This is probably because in `$redirect_uri` I’ve given the address of website where the app is hosted but when I try to change the `$redirect_uri` to app’s page tab address facebook give this error:

`An error occurred. Please try again later.`

```
<?php
    include ('src/facebook.php');
    $app_id = "160323532538730";
    $app_secret = "****************";
    $redirect_uri = "https://myhostingpage.com/landing.php";
    //$redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/Mypage/app_160323532538730";

    $config = array();
    $config["appId"] = $app_id;
    $config["secret"] = $app_secret;
    $config["fileUpload"] = true;
    // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user = $facebook -> getUser();

    if ($user) {
        $logoutUrl = $facebook -> getLogoutUrl();
        $user_profile = $facebook -> api('/me');
        $signed_request = $facebook -> getSignedRequest();

        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST["signed_request"], 2);
        $signed_request = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

        $access_token = null;
        if (!empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
            $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
        } else if (!empty($signed_request['oauth_token'])) {
            $access_token = $signed_request['oauth_token'];
        }

        if ($access_token != null) {
            $id = $signed_request["user_id"];
            $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
            $oauth_token = $signed_request["oauth_token"];
            $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
            if ($like_status) {
                echo "hello";
            } else {
                echo "Like this page";
            }
        } else if (!empty($_GET["error"])) {
            echo "user hasn't authorized your app";
        } else if (!empty($_GET["code"])) {
            $authorized_code = $_GET["code"];
            $authenticate_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $authorized_code . "";
            $access_token = $facebook -> getAccessToken();
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
            header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/Mypage/app_160323532538730');
        }
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook -> getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream email user_photos', 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri));
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "' </script>");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i am not working with facebook api more than 1 years, lots of things changed since. But i think its about canvas url problem, check your app configuration canvas_url is match with your file that located on host

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

`$redirect_uri` have to be your facebook page url,
and **Page Tab Url** field in facebook app configuration have to be your host path.

M.

Comment: but when I try to change the `$redirect_uri` to app’s page tab address facebook give this error:
`An error occurred. Please try again later.`
what to do with this?

Comment: try also to set **Web application** canvas url to your host